# Javascript replace() not working

Tags: javascript

My function to replace variables with "ç" is not working:

```
jQuery(function(){    

  var inputs, index;
  inputs = document.getElementsByTagName('input');
  for (index = 0; index < inputs.length; ++index) {
      // deal with inputs[index] element.
      if(inputs[index].getAttribute("data-masc") == 'livre')
      {
         inputs[index].onblur = function(){           
           jQuery(this).val(jQuery(this).val().replace("ç","c"));
         }        
      }
}
```

Input has returned "ç".

Comment: Check if the encoding of the file matches the encoding of the website.

Comment: Works for me (here: http://codepen.io/paulroub/pen/EmfHk). Note that the replacement *only* happens after entering, then leaving, the input field. This is as expected, since it's an `onblur` handler.

Answer (score 0):

As Halcyon warned me, the file encoding "js" and the codification of ASP.NET pages were different. Thanks for the help!